# how to get console information of chaincode.js when calling it from core hyperledger command

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, peer

Hi I have created a block chain network and i am trying to save the data into the peer and for that i am saving it into data.json file which contains some already existing data object but my code is not working:

```
> peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.tech.com:7050 --tls --cafile
> /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/tech.com/orderers/orderer.tech.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.tech.com-cert.pem
> -C mychannel -n mychain -l node -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","SBIN0000607", "ramji", "10000007","20500"]}' -P "OR
> ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

and this is my chaincode.js page code

```
const shim = require('fabric-shim'); 
const util = require('util'); 
var db = require('data.json'); 
var fs = require('fs');


var Chaincode = class {

  // Initialize the chaincode   async Init(stub) {
    console.info('========= example02 Init =========');
    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);
    let args = ret.params;
    // initialise only if 4 parameters passed.
    if (args.length != 4) {
      return shim.error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 4');
    }

    let Ifsc = args[0];
    let AccountHolder = args[2];
    let AccountNumber = args[1];
    let Amount = args[3];
    console.info("step2");


      console.info("step3");
      db.push({"Ifsc":Ifsc,"AccountHolder":AccountHolder,"AccountNumber":AccountNumber,"Amount":Amount})
      fs.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(db));
      return shim.success();

    //return shim.success();

  }

  async Invoke(stub) {
    let ret = stub.getFunctionAndParameters();
    console.info(ret);
    let method = this[ret.fcn];
    if (!method) {
      console.log('no method of name:' + ret.fcn + ' found');
      return shim.success();
    }
    try {
      let payload = await method(stub, ret.params);
      return shim.success(payload);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return shim.error(err);
    }   }

  async invoke(stub, args) {
    if (args.length != 3) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 3');
    }

    let A = args[0];
    let B = args[1];
    if (!A || !B) {
      throw new Error('asset holding must not be empty');
    }

    // Get the state from the ledger
    let Avalbytes = await stub.getState(A);
    if (!Avalbytes) {
      throw new Error('Failed to get state of asset holder A');
    }
    let Aval = parseInt(Avalbytes.toString());

    let Bvalbytes = await stub.getState(B);
    if (!Bvalbytes) {
      throw new Error('Failed to get state of asset holder B');
    }

    let Bval = parseInt(Bvalbytes.toString());
    // Perform the execution
    let amount = parseInt(args[2]);
    if (typeof amount !== 'number') {
      throw new Error('Expecting integer value for amount to be transaferred');
    }

    Aval = Aval - amount;
    Bval = Bval + amount;
    console.info(util.format('Aval = %d, Bval = %d\n', Aval, Bval));

    // Write the states back to the ledger
    await stub.putState(A, Buffer.from(Aval.toString()));
    await stub.putState(B, Buffer.from(Bval.toString()));

  }

  // Deletes an entity from state   async delete(stub, args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 1');
    }

    let A = args[0];

    // Delete the key from the state in ledger
    await stub.deleteState(A);   }

  // query callback representing the query of a chaincode   async query(stub, args) {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting name of the person to query')
    }

    let jsonResp = {};
    let A = args[0];

    // Get the state from the ledger
    let Avalbytes = await stub.getState(A);
    if (!Avalbytes) {
      jsonResp.error = 'Failed to get state for ' + A;
      throw new Error(JSON.stringify(jsonResp));
    }

    jsonResp.name = A;
    jsonResp.amount = Avalbytes.toString();
    console.info('Query Response:');
    console.info(jsonResp);
    return Avalbytes;   } };

shim.start(new Chaincode());
```

I am trying to store the data into data.json file but it is not working and i am also not able to the console info of the chaincode.js page so that i can debug.
Can anyone help me with this
Thanks !

Comment: Have you used the docker logs command to look at the stdout/stderr of the chaincode container ? If console.info doesn't output anything have you tried console.log ?

Comment: As a further suggestion, I would say that writing chaincode that saves data to a file on the peer filesystem is not a good idea for lots of reasons. Maybe using the private data facility coming in hyperledger fabric 1.2 would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
docker logs -f <container-name>
```

where `container-name` is name of container where chaincode has been instantiated. to view the console log. To get container-name try

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}"
```